# Colors of the flowers and its probability

Tags: probability

A wild species of plant has four different types:
40% have yellow flowers, 32% have red flowers, 18% have blue flowers, and the rest have white flowers.

a) What is the probability that the flowers on a randomly selected plant will be blue or red?

b) What is the probability that a colored (non-white) flower is blue?

Comment: a) $50$ percent and b) $20%$ percent

Comment: yup, but how did you get it? a) since blue and red is 32%+18%=50% can you just say that the probability of selecting blue or red is 0.5? No further calculations needed? and for b) its just 18/90?

Comment: Yep, it really is that simple :)

Comment: Actually (b) is not quite as straightforward as it looks.  If it asked for the probability that a randomly selected **plant** with coloured flowers has blue flowers, it would be just $18/90$.  But here it seems to be asking about a randomly selected **flower**.  It might be that e.g. the red type have more flowers than the blue ones, and that would change the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a) If $32\%$ have red flowers and $18\%$ have blue flowers, then $32+18=50\%$ have blue or red flowers. So $p=0.5$.

b) $40+32+18=90\%$ of flowers are non-white. So $10\%$ of flowers are white.

So then we scale up the proportions when we reduce our sample to just the $90\%$: to make $90=100$, we multiply by $\frac{100}{90} = \frac{10}{9}=1.111\ldots$. So $18 \cdot 1.111 = 19.9999\ldots = 20\%$.

Comment: That's what I got. It just seemed to easy to be true :) Thank you.

Comment: @user122674 It's certainly true, but it is a pretty easy problem ;). You're welcome!

Answer (score 1):

1. Blue **or** red suggests that you should add the two percents. $32 + 18 = 50%$. 
   So $50\% $ would be your first answer.
2. The number of non-white flowers is $40+32+18 = 90\%$. The number of blue flowers is 18, so the probability would be $18/90$. This is equal to $0.2$, so your final answer would be $20\%$.